# How to disable Logger in some classe's or a package?

Tags: gwt, logging

Using the standard GWT logger, is it possible to disable the Log statements for a complete package in the xml?
Or at least individual class's?

At the moment in the xml I can disable/endable all the logging with;

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
```

This seems to set it globally for all class's in all packages. Is it possible to do this selectively in the xml?

The guide here; http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html seems to only cover configuring the rootlogger, covering every log in the project. I am probably missing the obvious, but I don't "get" how to apply this selectively.

Given all my log statements are named;

```
protected static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("parent.childc");
```

It seems like selectively turning them on/off should be possible.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your logger instances really initialized as `Logger.getLogger("Example")`, you can't selectively turn them off and on, since they are all one instance called 'Example', so I'm assuming that this isn't actually the case.

For the most part, this is normal JULI - the standard mechanisms that work on the JVM will work here. This is doubly true in dev mode, which actually uses the standard java.util.logging.Logger implementation. So if you are just looking for cleaned up logging in dev mode, treat it as you would any other logger - from the root instance, find the package or class that you want to disable/enable, and set the log level to where you want it.

In compiled code this behaves a little differently, you may need to experiment a bit to see exactly how, I don't recall at the moment. However, you can still use `LogManager`, and can walk all existing loggers, packages:

```
LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
Enumeration<String> allLoggers = manager.getLoggerNames();
// for each String in the list, grab the logger via manager.getLogger
```

The advantage to this as opposed to `Logger.getLogger` is that this will only tell you about loggers that already exist, instead of creating them as you go. This way you could have a config file or url param that specifies which details you wish to see logged, and disable the rest.

EDIT: I ran an old sample I had made again, and it appears that the chief difference between dev mode and prod mode is that in prod mode you get a logger per package, with root at the top and the specific named loggers as 'leaf nodes', while in dev mode all loggers seem to be placed in the root logger directly, with no intermediate packages. It is possible that if you requested a logger for a particular package that it would then make one, but I didn't test to find out.

Comment: This is usefull, but this is a runtime solution.
I was hoping for something in the gwt.xml. I can, for example, turn all the logging off in the xml and it wont even compile those lines. I was hoping it could be done selectively too.

Also, you are correct, they arnt called "Example". Editing my question for clarity.